Division by zero when evaluating the limit
Assume Bloch electrons, governed by the Schrodinger equation $H\psi_k=E_k \psi_k$, where $\psi_k$ is the Bloch function with eigen energies $E_{k}$ and band velocity $v_{k}=\partial_k E_{k}$ with $k$ the crystal momentum, I would like to evaluate the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{q \to 0}  \left( \frac{v_{k}}{E_{k}-E_{k+q}} + \frac{v_{k}}{E_{k}-E_{k-q}} \right)
$$
where $q$ is a small shift of the crystal momentum. Is this limit zero or undefined?

I want to make the limit zero when $v_{nk} =0$.

Yes, you are right. $v_{nk}$ can be pulled out of the limit.

Thanks for your suggestion. I think I may ask on Math SE.

What is preventing you from evaluating this yourself?

I’ll be dropping the redundant band index. Using the definition of mass as:
$$
\partial_k^2E=\partial_k v =\frac1m
$$
by Taylor expansion:
$$
E(k+q)=E+vq+\frac{q^2}{2m}+o(q^2)
$$
So you get:
$$
\frac v{E-E(k+q)}+\frac v{E-E(k-q)}\to \frac1{mv}
$$
which is consistent dimensionally.

I think you used another Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x}$. A numerical test of $E=k^2$ shows the result is zero when q is very small, say 1e-15. But for larger q like 1e-10, it is your result.

I just checked that maybe numerical noise. You are right.

@XiaomingWang Basically the argument is$$\lim_{q\to0}\sum_\pm\frac{f'(k)}{f(k)-f(k\pm q)}=\frac{f''(k)}{f'(k)},$$which can be proven with Taylor expansion or by using L'Hôpital's rule twice.
